# Origin of nickname "River Lily"?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

What's the origin of the nickname "River Lily" that Ego called Meredith?

He refers to this nickname at least twice in the movie, so I suspect it has a special origin.

Does it come from somewhere in the Marvel canon or in the actual life of a co-creator of the film?

Comment: I suspect you're right about that, but the fact that it was ostentaciously referred to more than once by Ego makes me wonder why the emphasis -- an Easter Egg is usually more sly and subtle. Still .... could be!